# Steps and timing of the SEIS investment (in the UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-deduction, investing

All,
Assume that I am considering to invest £10K under the SEIS (Seed Enterprise Investment Scheme), on a UK startup in Jan 2016. In this case, can someone please advise the steps required and the tax year wrt which I will get the tax return?

Answer (score 3):

You make the investment in Jan 2016. Assuming the SEIS certificate is issued before 5th April 2016, then you will enter the SEIS investment on your 2015-2016 tax return and claim the relief in that year. If the certificate is not issued in time then you will enter it in the 2016-2017 tax return and get the relief then.

Note: I am assuming that the startup is already registered with the SEIS scheme by someone else - because if you are asking about how to go about that, I don't think that is an issue of personal finance.

Comment: Thanks Vicky! You answered my questions. From your answer, I get the feeling that the process of issuing a SEIS certificate can take 2+ months - am I right?

Comment: It certainly can take a while, yes. The only one I had experience of was around 2-3 months.